# How to make an expression from model fixed effects?

Tags: r

I have the fixed effects from lmer in an object, fixed.effects3, and I want to make an expression that I can use as a formula for plotting with curve(). I tried this:

```
math.growth <- expression(eval(fixed.effects3[1]) + x*eval(fixed.effects3[2]) + x^2*eval(fixed.effects3[3]))
```

but then when I try to plot it with curve() I get these errors:

```
curve(math.growth, from=-2, to=3)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
could not find function "math.growth"
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `curve` can also take a function; that should be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using an included dataset, extending it to your case should be very straightforward; if you use global assignment like I did below, be sure to have an obscure variable name:

```
fe<<-fixef(lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject) + (0+Days|Subject), sleepstudy))
fef<-function(x) fe[1] + fe[2]*x
curve(fef, from = 1, to = 10)
```